# Ajax runs my insert query twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am working in WordPress and I run a function to insert a row in database with ajax. Ajax runs but for some reason insert operation is performed twice.

Below is my code
Ajax

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on("submit","#myvoteform", function(e) {
    //form is intercepted
    e.preventDefault();
        //serialize the form which contains secretcode
        var sentdata = $(this).serializeArray();

        //Add the additional param to the data        
        sentdata.push({
            name: 'action',
            value: 'votes'
        })

        //set sentdata as the data to be sent
        $.post(yes.ajaxurl, sentdata, function (res) { //start of funciton
            //$("#myresult").append(res.l);
        //  $("#myresult").html("");
            $("#myresult").html(res);


 //$.parseJSON(data);
            return false;
        } //end of function
        ,
        'json'); //set the dataType as json, so you will get the parsed data in the callback
    });  // submit end here

    }); //vote function ends here
```

PHP code
Insert function

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_votes', 'votes' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_votes', 'votes');

add_shortcode('sketchfamvotes','voteus');

function voteus(){  
// register & enqueue a javascript file called globals.js
wp_register_script( 'votess', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/ajaxinsert.js", array( 'jquery' ) ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'votess' );

// use wp_localize_script to pass PHP variables into javascript
wp_localize_script( 'votess', 'yes', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

function votes ()

{//echo json_encode("pakistan zindabad"); die();

       $cat =$_POST['category'];
       $comp = $_POST['competition'];   
       $uid= $_POST['uid'];


       global $wpdb;

        $userid = $_POST['userid'];
        $myvote = 1;

    if($wpdb->insert(
        'votes',
        array(
                'votes' => 1,
                'competition' => $comp,
                'uid' => $uid
            )
) == false) {wp_die(json_encode('Database Insertion failed')); die();} else {echo json_encode('your vote was successfully recorded');die();}

}
```

Below is my form which is the result of another ajax call. I'm not pasting the full ajax php function but just showing how my form looks like.

```
if( is_array($results) && count($results) > 0  ) {

            $form = "";
            foreach( $results as $result ) {

            $form .= '<form id="myvoteform" action="" method="post">';
            $form .= "<input name='category' type='hidden' value='$result->category'>";

            $form .= "<img src='$result->path' width='150' height='150' >" . '<br><br>';
            $form .= "<input name='uid' type='text' value='$result->uid'>";
            $form .= "<input name='competition' type='hidden' value='$result->competition'>";
            $form .= "<input name='userid' value'$result->uid' type='text'>".'<br>';
            $form .= $result->category.'<br>';
            $form .= $result->uid.'<br>';
            $form .= $result->votessum.'<br>';
            $form .= "<input style='margin-bottom:30px;' id='votebutton' value='vote' name='submit' type='submit'/></form>";
```

Comment: If you look in (for example) Google Chrome Developer tools, is the ajax call executed twice in quick succession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this modified code - jquery .off()

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).off().on("submit","#myvoteform", function(e) {
    //form is intercepted
    e.preventDefault();
        //serialize the form which contains secretcode
        var sentdata = $(this).serializeArray();

        //Add the additional param to the data        
        sentdata.push({
            name: 'action',
            value: 'votes'
        })

        //set sentdata as the data to be sent
        $.post(yes.ajaxurl, sentdata, function (res) { //start of funciton
            //$("#myresult").append(res.l);
        //  $("#myresult").html("");
            $("#myresult").html(res);


 //$.parseJSON(data);
            return false;
        } //end of function
        ,
        'json'); //set the dataType as json, so you will get the parsed data in the callback
    });  // submit end here

    }); //vote function ends here
```

Comment: Or you can maintain a flag with boolean true false.

Comment: Shelim .... I added this code but the data is still inserted twice in the mysql database. Please suggest a solution and also tell that why does it behave like this when I have written 1 insert query only

Comment: Wow Shalim you are the man ... it worked ... you are the guru ... also tell me that why do this happen just for my knowledge and can we check through inspect or firebug that how many times code is executing

Comment: Have you checked in console ? is your ajax request goes twice or once? please check it ?

Comment: Its my pleasure. It is due to event handling.Jquery off() destroy all previously fired submit event in your case and releases a new event.Please upvote if really the answer was helpfull.